# Running through its corridors

Tags: riddle, knowledge

It shifts and move before their sights

It rumbles with shifting every night

Within its walls many are long trapped

Running through its corridors in hope

Eight ways and for one man each

To find a way out in their reach

Flesh and metal lurk in the night

Doors shut them at sunset's sight

Get in before they close at last

Or your death won't be so fast

It took a mind bright to see the pattern

Before they left the halls of ivy and fern

Thought they would never come back again

But others in mind had other plans

Many they took, for special they were in mind

And locked them in the walls in and behind

When a lad found out from a turn of a book

He led a long rescue and had one last look

It's stone walls last seen in moments of flight

As it crumbles and falls in last sight

---

What is it? Please explain each line!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the answer is

> The maze in the Mazerunner series
>
>  I've tried to explain each line, but to be honest, I haven't read the books or seen the movies...

It shifts and move before their sights
It rumbles with shifting every night

> The walls of the maze change every night

Within its walls many are long trapped

> The characters are all trapped inside a maze

Running through its corridors in hope

> "Runners" move through the maze quickly, keeping track of the changing walls

Eight ways and for one man each

> The maze is divided into eight sections

To find a way out in their reach

> They run as fast as they can to cover as much ground as possible

Flesh and metal lurk in the night

> Creatures in the maze know as Grievers

Doors shut them at sunset's sight

> At night, doors shut to keep Grievers out of the Glade

Get in before they close at last
Or your death won't be so fast

> If runners are not back by night, they have to face the nocturnal Grievers

It took a mind bright to see the pattern

> The main character realized the maze changed according to a pattern

Before they left the halls of ivy and fern

> The maze is made of tall concrete walls covered in ivy

Thought they would never come back again
But others in mind had other plans

> The characters did not plan to ever return but the WICKED organization had it planned that they would need to return (see below)

Many they took, for special they were in mind

> A group of "Immunes" were taken who were immune to a brain disease central to the book

And locked them in the walls in and behind

> They were locked inside the walls of the maze which the earlier group had escaped from

When a lad found out from a turn of a book

> When a main character wakes from a procedure, he finds a note (connected to book?) telling him he needs to free the Immunes

He led a long rescue and had one last look

> He proceeds to go back to the original maze (one last look) and rescue them

It's stone walls last seen in moments of flight

> After the rescue, they escape the maze in a last "flight"

As it crumbles and falls in last sight

> As they are doing so, the walls explode

Comment: @RewanDemontay Made some edits!